# argumenterror invalid byte sequence in utf-8 error on Ruby server when uploading images from Android

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

Code for posting photos and some data to server.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.STORIES_URL);
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" + s);

                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uuid", "1234567890"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "Title"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subtitle", "Subtitle"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("private", "true"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/0.jpg"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[uuid]", "1234567890"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[timelineDate]", "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[caption]", "Byte 1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[photo]", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/0.jpg"));

                for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : nameValuePairs) {
                    if (nameValuePair.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo") || nameValuePair.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bytes[photo]")) {
                        File imgFile = new File(nameValuePair.getValue());
                        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(imgFile, "image/jpeg");
                        multipartEntity.addPart("story[photo]", fileBody);
                    } else {
                        multipartEntity.addPart("story[" + nameValuePair.getName() + "]", new StringBody(nameValuePair.getValue()));
                    }
                }              

                httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

And in response I got error Completed 500 Internal Server Error: "argumenterror invalid byte sequence in utf-8"

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.STORIES_URL);
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" + s);

                MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uuid", "1234567890"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "My Title"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subtitle", "My Subtitle"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("private", "true"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/0.jpg"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[uuid]", "1234567890"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[timelineDate]", "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[caption]", "Byte 1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bytes[photo]", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/0.jpg"));

                for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : nameValuePairs) {
                    if (nameValuePair.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo") || nameValuePair.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bytes[photo]")) {
                        File imgFile = new File(nameValuePair.getValue());
                        builder.addBinaryBody("story[photo]", imgFile, ContentType.create("image/jpg"), "photo.jpg");
                    } else {
                        builder.addTextBody("story[" + nameValuePair.getName() + "]", nameValuePair.getValue());
                    }
                }

                HttpEntity build = builder.build();
                httpPost.setEntity(build);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
```